# Is there a way to customise the date format?

Tags: feature-request, date-format

This *Sep 16 '18* business annoys me to no end. Like most of the world's population my brain wants to parse dates either little or big endian.

I'd like to change the displayed date format to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but I use a number of devices (on occasion even the SE App on android). So even if I wanted to, using a custom css/js hack on my browser is not an option. But I cannot find an option to set this in my profile.

Can we **please** have this?!

---

**Edit:** I'm talking about the date format of older posts, where the "a few minutes ago" thing doesn't apply anymore.

I'm turning this support question into a feature-request, as per comments.

Comment: Can you specify where is this date to be clear? I know what you meant but I had to search for a while to find example. Hovering on "asked 10 mins ago" or "Asked today" already uses ISO format.

Comment: @Piro Anywhere where the short month name format is used. So once a post is over 2 days old and flag history pages are a couple of examples.

Comment: I changed the tag accordingly.

Comment: I see questions with "asked Sep 5 at 13:53 ". So this probably applies only to posts from previous years.

Comment: @Piro That Post is from 2011!

Comment: Doesn't matter @bitmask your request is still a duplicate of it. Given that it was asked for in 2011 and not implemented means that there is a good chance it isn't going to change.

Comment: And while they're at it, they could remove that useless "yesterday" special case. "Yesterday" lasts 24 hours. I like the "x hours ago" case, because it's easier to grab than the full date, and accurate enough. The general date format is also accurate. But just "yesterday" is way too vague.

Comment: @Dave I think repeating the request for a feature after **eight years** is legitimate. Esp. since it wasn't explicitly rejected.

Comment: Won't argue that but it's still going to be considered a duplicate.

Comment: What happened to MSE? Where are all the downvotes for suggestions? This is not how I know MSE.